# Why does networkmanager change device state to unavailable?

Tags: networkmanager, yocto, nmcli, petalinux

Using a Yocto distribution with NetworkManager and NetworkManager-nmcli installed, I am not able to have my wifi wlan0 device leaving the unavailable state.
The error message I have is:

```
device (wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
```

My question is how could I know which program is managing the device?
I uninstalled and removed all sysvinit scripts that could create the network device and still have the same issue.

I narrowed it down to the fact that when NetworkManager is started, it creates the wlan0 device and then switches it to unavailable as explained above.

This is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

This is my /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=keyfile,ifupdown
rc-manager=symlink
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

The /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi
```

From my (probably poor) understanding, all these seem fine. I do not get why the wlan0 is still in "unavailable"??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

**EDIT**
Folowing @thaller suggestion, I enabled the trace level log

```
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6226] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: success changing link: success
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6227] platform: (wlan0) link: setting hardware address to 02:42:58:70:A1:F9
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6231] platform-linux: do-request-link: 3
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6231] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 3: wlan0 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? not-init addrgenmode none addr 02:42:58:70:A1:F9 brd FF:FF:FF:FF:
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6232] platform: (wlan0) signal: link changed: 3: wlan0 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? init addrgenmode none addr 02:42:58:70:A1:F9 brd FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF driver rtl8821au rx:78,
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6233] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 19: 3: wlan0 <DOWN;broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? not-init addrgenmode none addr 02:42:58:70:A1:F9 brd FF:FF:FF:FF
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6234] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: success changing link: success
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6234] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): hw-addr: hardware address now 02:42:58:70:A1:F9
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.info NetworkManager[1195]: <info>  [1646917953.6240] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 02:42:58:70:A1:F9 (scanning)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6242] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): bringing up device 3
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6242] platform: (wlan0) link: setting up
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6243] platform-linux: link: change 3: flags: set 0x1/0x1 ([up] / [up])
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6244] platform-linux: do-request-link: 3
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6245] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 3: wlan0 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? not-init addrgenmode none addr 02:42:58:70:A1:F
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6245] platform: (wlan0) signal: link changed: 3: wlan0 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? init addrgenmode none addr 02:42:58:70:A1:F9 brd FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF drive
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6247] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 21: 3: wlan0 <UP,LOWER_UP;broadcast,multicast,up,lowerup> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? not-init addrgenmode none addr 02:42:58:70:A1:
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6247] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: success changing link: success
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6248] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): ip4-config: update (commit=1, new-config=(nil))
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6248] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): ip4-config: clear IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6253] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6255] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6255] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6256] dbus-object[db112265116d3c2f]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/1"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6258] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): ip6-config: update (commit=1, new-config=(nil))
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6259] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): ip6-config: clear IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6263] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6265] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6265] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6266] dbus-object[5827083ac52f43c8]: unexport: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/1"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6285] supplicant: (wlan0): creating new supplicant interface
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6289] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): add_pending_action (2): 'waiting-for-supplicant'
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6290] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): device not yet available for transition to DISCONNECTED
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6313] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): connectivity state changed from UNKNOWN to NONE
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6316] manager: connectivity checking indicates NONE
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6323] dispatcher: (2) dispatching action 'connectivity-change'
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6327] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): connectivity state changed from UNKNOWN to NONE
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6335] device[8ad453a3b5b754fb] (wlan0): remove_pending_action (1): 'in-state-change'
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.info nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (0 scripts)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': environment: CONNECTIVITY_STATE=NONE
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': environment: NM_DISPATCHER_ACTION=connectivity-change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.info nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': completed: no scripts
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6347] create NMVpnManager singleton (6588803e3521b96d)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6347] manager: creating virtual devices...
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6348] setting up local loopback
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6349] platform: (lo) link: setting up
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6349] platform-linux: link: change 1: flags: set 0x1/0x1 ([up] / [up])
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6350] platform-linux: do-request-link: 1
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6352] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 23: 1: lo <UP,LOWER_UP;loopback,up,running,lowerup> mtu 65536 arp 772 loopback? not-init addrgenmode eui64 addr 00:00:00:00:0
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6353] ethtool[1]: ETHTOOL_GDRVINFO, lo: failed: Operation not supported
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6354] platform-linux: do-change-link[1]: success changing link: success
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6366] firewall: D-Bus name for firewalld has no owner (firewall stopped)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6370] dns-sd-resolved[93c36e7af7f93bfa]: D-Bus name for systemd-resolved has no owner
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6384] dispatcher: (1) succeeded but no scripts invoked
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6390] dispatcher: (2) succeeded but no scripts invoked
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.info NetworkManager[1195]: <info>  [1646917953.6397] ovsdb: Could not connect: No such file or directory
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6398] ovsdb: disconnecting from ovsdb, retry 0
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.info NetworkManager[1195]: <info>  [1646917953.6399] supplicant: wpa_supplicant stopped
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6402] device[53bb033d9641aa44] (lo): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0xaaaaf2bb8130)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6402] dbus-object[e01a38d512fcba77]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/2"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6408] device[53bb033d9641aa44] (lo): ip4-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/2)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6418] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6420] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6420] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6422] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/disable_ipv6': '0'
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6423] device[53bb033d9641aa44] (lo): ip6-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0xaaaaf2b9f370)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6424] dbus-object[d1948f7b92c13977]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/2"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6429] device[53bb033d9641aa44] (lo): ip6-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/2)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6434] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6436] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6436] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6437] device[c503cba53b9e71c5] (sit0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0xaaaaf2bb84c0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6438] dbus-object[db112265116d3c2f]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/3"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6443] device[c503cba53b9e71c5] (sit0): ip4-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/3)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6448] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6450] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6450] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6452] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/disable_ipv6': '0'
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6453] device[c503cba53b9e71c5] (sit0): ip6-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0xaaaaf2b9f7b0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6453] dbus-object[2c07d4e5110af889]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/3"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6457] device[c503cba53b9e71c5] (sit0): ip6-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/3)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6463] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6464] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6465] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6466] device[c1055a26277ac48d] (usb0): ip4-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0xaaaaf2bb85f0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6467] dbus-object[9d6eaa32c97d075e]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6472] device[c1055a26277ac48d] (usb0): ip4-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/4)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6483] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6485] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6485] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6487] platform-linux: sysctl: reading '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/usb0/disable_ipv6': '0'
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6488] device[c1055a26277ac48d] (usb0): ip6-config: update (commit=0, new-config=0xaaaaf2b9fae0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <trace> [1646917953.6489] dbus-object[f2d73358dc9003e5]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/4"
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6495] device[c1055a26277ac48d] (usb0): ip6-config: set IP Config instance (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/4)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6501] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6502] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6503] dns-mgr: (device_ip_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6506] manager: (lo): assume: don't assume because not managed
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6507] manager: (sit0): assume: don't assume because not managed
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6507] manager: (usb0): assume: don't assume because not managed
Mar 10 13:12:33 nclab-kol-2021 daemon.debug NetworkManager[1195]: <debug> [1646917953.6508] manager: startup complete is waiting for device 'wlan0' (waiting-for-supplicant)
```

I do not know what really to do with it. It seems that the network manager is creating the device than...

Answer (score 1):

most likely because there is a problem with wpa_supplicant.

To debug issues in NetworkManager, check the logs. Almost always it is a good idea to collect `level=TRACE` logs. Read https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/main/contrib/fedora/rpm/NetworkManager.conf#L27 for hints about logging.